# Performing a multiplication and showing the result in a Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, multiplication

I have a winform comboboxes,textboxes ...etc. richTextBox1,textbox txtTotal and a btnAdd. When I click btnAdd few times I'm adding the values in richTextBox1 then, the total in txtTotal. My question is: How can I multiply them in txtTotal?

```
class Multy
{       
    public decimal Odds;
    public decimal Stake;
    public Multy()
    {}
}

private List<Multy> matches = new List<Multy>();

    private decimal transactionTotal;

    public decimal TransactionTotal
    {
        get { return transactionTotal; }
        set
        { 
            transactionTotal = value;
            txtTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", transactionTotal);
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        matches = new List<Multy>();
        Multy match = new Multy();

        match.Odds = decimal.Parse(txtOdds.Text);
        match.Stake = decimal.Parse(txtStake.Text);
        matches.Add(match);

        decimal l_Odds;
        decimal l_Stake;

        string strOdds;
        string strStake;

        string strOutputLine;

        foreach (Multy m in matches)
        {               
            l_Odds = m.Odds;
            l_Stake = m.Stake;

            strOdds = l_Odds.ToString();
            strStake = l_Stake.ToString();

            strOutputLine = String.Format("{0}{1}{2} ",strOdds,strStake, Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(strOutputLine);

            TransactionTotal = transactionTotal + (decimal)m.Odds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do  you want to multiply ??

Comment: Odds or Stake for example (see the last code) now I'm adding in txtTotal.

Comment: Do you want to add or multiply ??

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding with the `btnAdd`, and if you like to keep it and do multiplication also, then you should put an another button `btnMultiply` to perform your job.

And this is quite simple. Just convert string to double, then multiply(`*`) and show it to `txtTotal` after converting it to String.

Comment: it doesn't work for (*) or (/). In the last code I convert it to decimal but it works only for (+) and (-).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Decimal.Multiply` method?

```
var total = Decimal.Multiply(this.TransactionTotal, m.Odds);
```

Comment: This line: `match.Odds = decimal.Parse(txtOdds.Text);` would suggest you are incorrect.  The class object `match` eventually becomes an interation of `m`, so `m.Odds` should be `decimal`.

Comment: My mistake, I thought it was two classes `Match` and `Multy` with incompatible types. Will update my answer.